# Using ansible uri form-multipart inline

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to post dns updates to fusionlayer infinity using ansible, it should be possible by using form-multipart body_format but I can't seem to make it work.

I'm essentially trying to replicate the functionality of this curl call:

`curl -k -X PUT -u "$1:$2" $3 --form $4'="{\"name\": \"'$5'\", \"type\": \"'$6'\", \"value\": \"'$7'\"}"'`

I'm trying now with:

```
   - name: Add records
     ansible.builtin.uri:
       url: "{{ infinity.url_base }}/zones/{{ infinity.zone_id }}"
       user: "{{ user_infinity.user }}"
       password: "{{ user_infinity.pass }}"
       method: PUT
       body_format: form-multipart
       body:
         add: '{"name": "{{ item }}", "type": "A", "value": "{{ app_hosts[item] }}"}'
     with_items: "{{ app_hosts }}"
```

which gives me error

`"msg": "failed to parse body as form-multipart: at least one of filename or content must be provided"`

even though the invocation looks just right to me.

```
"invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "body": {
                "add": {
                    "name": "recordname",
                    "type": "A",
                    "value": "10.5.13.15"
                }
            },
            "body_format": "form-multipart",
            "ca_path": null,
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "creates": null,
            "dest": null,
            "follow_redirects": "safe",
            "force": false,
            "force_basic_auth": false,
            "group": null,
            "headers": {},
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "method": "PUT",
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "remote_src": false,
            "removes": null,
            "return_content": false,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "status_code": [
                200
            ],
            "timeout": 30,
            "unix_socket": null,
            "unsafe_writes": false,
            "url": "https://ipam/rest/v1/zones/56451",
            "url_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "url_username": "username",
            "use_gssapi": false,
            "use_proxy": true,
            "user": "username",
            "validate_certs": true
        }
```

How should the form-multipart be actually used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have gotten bitten by ansible's auto-coercion behavior due to the leading `{` when used in a jinja2 context. You can see that happening in your `"invocation"` logging where it turned your `add` *string* into an `add` *dictionary* -- it's due to the leading `{` causing ansible to think you meant for `add` to be a `dict` and it "helped" you. Strangely, it only seems to only happen in combination with the `with_items:` part, as I could not reproduce that behavior without the looping

It seems being explicit about the use of jinja2 evaluation, and then being explicit about the `|string` filter made it work for me.

```yaml
       ansible.builtin.uri:
         ... as before ...
         body_format: form-multipart
         body:
           add: '{{ {"name": item, "type": "A", "value": app_hosts[item]} | to_json | string }}'
```

You will also note that `"name": "{{ item }}"` changed to `"name": item`; that's because the use of nested jinja2 evaluations is always a bug

Comment: Super, this worked. There seems to be quite a bunch of these kinks to learn in Ansible :)