# Ansible uri POST with body containing as key value JSON

Tags: ansible

I have a config_file with values in the format: key-value pair
e.g. `a: "{\"type\": \"some_type\"}"`

Everything is ok. Util I tried to pass this JSON value as value inside uri utility:

```
 - name: 'Push config values'
    uri:
      url: '{{ uri }}/api/{{ item.key }}'
      method: POST
      body: '{"alias":"{{ item.key }}","key":"{{ item.key }}","value":"{{ item.value }}"}'
      body_format: json
      validate_certs: no
      status_code: 204
      headers:
        X-Token: "{{ token }}"
    with_dict: '{{ config_overrides_file }}'
    register: response
```

I tried different way of escaping, also filter combination | from_json | to_json. But nothing is working. I got `'failed to parse JSON input: invalid character ''t'' after object key:value pair'` in case of escaping
Probably, exist some standard approach to handle it?

I found just one way to achieve what I want: instead of `a: "{\"type\": \"some_type\"}"` this value in config file it could be `a: {"type": "some_type"}` and in uri it will be body: `{"alias":"{{ item.key }}","key":"{{ item.key }}", "value": {{ item.value | to_json }}}`. It's working approach but I would like not create additional task for json and non-json properties for such type of request.

P.S. When I hardcode this value everything is ok

Answer (score 1):

You're getting bitten by ansible's "helpful" behavior of coercing *any* string it finds that starts with `{` *back* into a `dict`; the usual fix for that is to send it explicitly through `|string` to indicate to ansible you do not wish for that to happen. For sure any `loop`-ish behavior on a task (`with_dict:` being one of them) makes that problem much worse, because ansible gets really, really weird about coercion and recursive jinja2 templates in that circumstance

```yaml
 - name: test data for SO
   set_fact:
     config_values_file:
        a: '{"type": "some_type"}'

 - name: 'Push config values'
   uri:
      url: '{{ uri }}/api/{{ item.key }}'
      method: POST
      body: >-
        {{ {"alias": item.key,
             "key": item.key,
             "value": item.value|string
            } }}
      body_format: json
      validate_certs: no
      status_code: 204
      headers:
        X-Token: "{{ token }}"
   with_dict: '{{ config_overrides_file }}'
   register: response
```

POSTs:
`{"alias": "a", "key": "a", "value": "{\"type\": \"some_type\"}"}` which I believe is what you were asking for

Comment: I finally found the other time this behavior manifested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69902322/225016

Comment: thank for your response. I haven't noticed this answer because the title isn't obvious to main topic